# Python: Interacting with Oracle database without using ODBC

Tags: python, oracle, orm

I am new to python and currently writing a module to write error logs into Oracle database. Its not possible to install ODBC libraries on the server for this task so I am wondering what is the best way to handle this without using ODBC (such as pyodbc). I am advised to use ORMs so any of you have some idea about this? I am using python 2.6.5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) doesn't use ODBC but you have to install the Oracle client tools.

If the JVM and [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) is an [option](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) for you the Oracle Thin Driver for JDBC can be used without ODBC or the client tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are apparently a number of options, a mere google search away:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle

My guess is that [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) is the one you want.

Comment: Yea, I found that too. But is there any internal libraries within python that handles such task?